# How to get Progress Update if software is undergoing a long process in c# windows application

Tags: c#, database, winforms, process, loading

How to get **Progress Update** if **software is undergoing a long process** in c# windows application?

I am working on a project which is **retrieving data from database** but **sometimes it takes a little more time** depending upon CPU usage and at **loading time i want to show message that data is loading**. How to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show message before loading data.
2. Load Data.
3. Hide/Remove the message.

**Edit:**

To show after specific interval.

1. Start a timer for an interval which you think counts as long.
2. Start loading data.
3. On timer tick, stop the timer display the message.
4. Hide/Remove the message after data loading is complete.

if you want it to become more meaning full, then as the timer tick check how much data has been loaded, lets say only 50% then show the message. If lets say 90% then don't show the message.

Comment: i dont want to show a message where the data is just coming in half a sec.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show progress through some GUI. 
Please have a look at these links:

- [Progress Bars](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You)
- [Basics of Threads](http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm)

Comment: progress bar is for if the work is heavy but in my case it takes max 2 sec and i want to get if my app. is in long process or not.

Comment: Well, you need not use progress bar per se. I only pointed out how to manage UI in a different thread. It is entirely upto you to show what the UI needs to be - progress bar/counter/time ticking etc.

Comment: i am already using threads just my need of the time is i want to check if my application is under a long procedure or not

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework has a class BackgroundWorker that deals with situations like your case

you can read about it here: [How to use background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

1. display ShowModel form containing Loading image
2. run the worker to load the data
3. once the Background worker completed (you can know by handle the
   event RunWorkerCompleted),  close this form in this event

hope that this will help you

Comment: i am already using threads just my need of the time is i want to check if my application is under a long procedure or not.

Comment: if your query will take less than 1 sec, the end user will not feel that something happened ( showing the form and closing it), he will see it in one case, if the query took more than 1 sec. and to know if the query will take long time, you should collect data from sql about the query will be executed.